# error when run "composer install"

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

i got this error when tried to run "composer install" for a laravel 5 project:

```
You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for intervention/image 2.3.4 -> satisfiable by intervention/image[2.3.4].
    - intervention/image 2.3.4 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
```

I've tried set the PHP.ini xdebug to false, and still got this error. What should i do to solve this error? how to disable the xdebug? or is there anything else that should i did? thanks.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Your missing the `fileinfo` extension for PHP as it says in the last line. You need to install that.

Comment: im using windows 10, and i never did anything to the fileinfo extension for the php.

Comment: find your php.ini(for cli), then line `;extension=php_fileinfo.dll` and remove `;` also check my answer.

Comment: it turns out i have 2 php folder contains 2 php.ini files. one in xampp folder, and one in IIS express folder, the PHP.ini load configuration in cmd show the path to IIS Express, i think it should be PHP.ini in xampp.  

the one with ;extension=php_fileinfo.dll  is in php.ini file at xampp folder, but the load configuration show the path to IIS, How to get it back to the PHP.ini in xampp folder?

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with XDEBUG. You just haven't installed `fileinfo` extension which is causing the problem.

Check this: [requires ext-fileinfo. How do I add that into my composer.json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771117/requires-ext-fileinfo-how-do-i-add-that-into-my-composer-json-file) and [this](http://php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php)

Comment: I didn't found the ;extension=php_fileinfo.dll part in the PHP.ini in Load configuration path, there is PHP.ini in my xampp/php... , and i found that extension there, but the xampp/php/php.ini path was not the path the load configuration told me, but i've remove the comment in finleinfo at xampp/php/php.ini , and nothing happen, still got the same error.

Comment: you need locate php.ini that is responsible for your CLI php configuratin

Comment: it turns out i have 2 php folder contains 2 php.ini files. one in xampp folder, and one in IIS express folder, the PHP.ini load configuration in cmd show the path to IIS Express, i think it should be PHP.ini in xampp. How to get it back to the PHP.ini in xampp folder? thanks.