# Composer fails installing laraveldaily/quickadmin

Tags: laravel, composer-php

While intstalling [laraveldaily/quickadmin](https://github.com/LaravelDaily/quickadmin) I got the following error.
Please help me to solve my problem.

[image: composer output]

Comment: Have you installed `intervention/image` like it states?

Comment: See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771117/requires-ext-fileinfo-how-do-i-add-that-into-my-composer-json-file)

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the error message

> intervetion/image requires ext-fileinfo

You need to enable `ext-fileinfo` by editing your `php.ini` and change the following line by removing the `;` at the beginning.

From:

```
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

To:

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

#### Find out which `php.ini` to edit

Run `php --ini` from a terminal. Make sure you run this command from terminal as the CLI version of PHP may have loaded another `php.ini` than the web version. Your `phpinfo()` may not contain the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

As error describes, `laraveldaily/quickadmin` requires `intervention/image` which again requires `ext-fileinfo`. This library is maintained by `php_fileinfo.dll`

`php_fileinfo.dll` is a dll(library file) which contains modules to guess the content type and encoding of a file by looking for certain magic byte sequences at specific positions within the file.

To fix this error first go to the directory of your php installation.Go to the `ext` folder and make sure that php_fileinfo.dll is present.

Now open your `php.ini` file (To locate that, type `php --ini` on the command line, also suggested by @peh) .

In the `php --ini` file just add the following line.

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

and recheck with the composer.