# Using brew to install php file info

Tags: php, php-extension

Is there a way to install php extension file info using brew? Or if you have another way, it will be great if you want to tell me.

I've already tried brew install fileinfo php71-fileinfo,

but i've got nothing.

thanks

Comment: look **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771117/requires-ext-fileinfo-how-do-i-add-that-into-my-composer-json-file)** , one of the answers details a PECL install procedure.  fileinfo not available with brew.

Comment: yes i've already uncomment the extenstion, but i've got this error when trying to restart my valet server *i am laravel user

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php71/7.1.2_13/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_fileinfo.dll' -