# error while uploading image PHP Fileinfo extension must be installed/enabled to use Intervention Image

Tags: php, laravel, wampserver

Error while uploading an image from any other path in my system:

> PHP Fileinfo extension must be installed/enabled to use Intervention
>   Image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Fileinfo extension must be installed/enabled to use Intervention Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44426078/php-fileinfo-extension-must-be-installed-enabled-to-use-intervention-image)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using WAMPServer the `FileInfo` extension should have been enabled out of the box.

But you can enable it easily using the wampmanager menus:

```
(left click) wampmanager->PHP-> Php Extensions ...
```

then click on `FileInfo` if it does not have a green tick beside it. This will amend the `php.ini` file and then restart Apache to activate the change.

[image]

Now if you are getting this error while using the PHP CLI then you will have to manually edit the `php.ini` file that controls the PHP CLI environment. Its not the same one that controls PHP under Apache.

So edit `C:\wamp64\bin\php\phpx.y.x\php.ini` where `phpx.y.x` is the version of PHP you are using.

Find the line `#extension=fileinfo` and remove the `#`.

Next time you run the PHP CLI it should pickup that change