# Fileinfo extension must be installed/enabled to use Intervention Image

Tags: laravel

I am using a shared host and I got this error while image uploading. I checked fileinfo checked box in CPanel but still have this error.
I am using laravel 7 and php 7.3 and  Intervention Image 2.5 .

PHP Fileinfo extension must be installed/enabled to use Intervention Image

Comment: Does [https://stackoverflow.com/a/46838300](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46838300/6212294) answers you?

Answer (score 0):

It is work for me
I add these code on .htacess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ server.php
</IfModule>
```