# how to resolve this error on laravel project creation time

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Problem 1

```
  - laravel/framework[v8.40.0, ..., 8.x-dev] 
    require league/flysystem ^1.1 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev].
           
  - league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHPs fileinfo extension.

  - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^8.40 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.40.0, ..., 8.x-dev].
```

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- C:\Program Files\php\v7.4\php.ini
You can also run `PHP --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

I got this error and I try all this and the app process is the same as suggested in other solutions.
But my issue was not resolved.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23779014/6212294) help you?

Comment: What **exactly** did you try?