# composer update error -composer version 2.6.2

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Composer cannot update and have errors:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

**Problem 1** :

```
- laravel/framework[v10.10.0, ..., v10.22.0] require league/flysystem ^3.8.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[3.8.0, ..., 3.15.1].
- league/flysystem[3.3.0, ..., 3.14.0] require league/mime-type-detection ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.13.0].
- league/flysystem[3.15.0, ..., 3.15.1] require league/flysystem-local ^3.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem-local[3.15.0].
- league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.3.0] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.2.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
- league/mime-type-detection[1.4.0, ..., 1.13.0] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
- league/flysystem-local 3.15.0 require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
- Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^10.10 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v10.10.0, ..., v10.22.0].
```

I already try to do:

```
Composer update

Composer install
```

but still cannot resolve the error.

Comment: "_Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension._" Right there in the error message

Comment: May I know what file info extension do you mean?

Comment: PHP's fileinfo extension ;) There's a link [requires ext-fileinfo. How do I add that into my composer.json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771117/requires-ext-fileinfo-how-do-i-add-that-into-my-composer-json-file) at the top that details how to install it

Answer (score 1):

I had tried `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs` and it works!

Plus I did `composer update --ignore-platform-reqs` to update composer files. Now can run php artisan serve

Comment: Keep in mind that this might work for the installation of packages, but there can still be problems when running your application. There's a good reason that `league/flsystem` depends on `ext-fileinfo`