# Errors when trying to create first project in Laravel 10

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to create a new Laravel project in a new Laravel install on a PC running Windows 10. I installed current versions of NodeJS, npm, VS Code, PHP, Composer, Git, 7-zip. Then I installed Laravel via Composer. All installs appeared to be successful. I created a Laravel folder and then a Project 1 folder within it. I opened VS Code on Project 1. I opened a VS Code terminal and executed the following from my Laravel folder:

```
laravel new demo-app2
```

Here is the output from the command:

```
  | |                             | |
  | |     __ _ _ __ __ ___   _____| |
  | |    / _` | '__/ _` \ \ / / _ \ |
  | |___| (_| | | | (_| |\ V /  __/ |
  |______\__,_|_|  \__,_| \_/ \___|_|


 Would you like to install a starter kit?:
  [none     ] No starter kit
  [breeze   ] Laravel Breeze
  [jetstream] Laravel Jetstream
 > none


 Which testing framework do you prefer?:
  [0] PHPUnit
  [1] Pest
 > 0


 Would you like to initialize a Git repository? (yes/no) [no]:
 > no

    Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./demo-app2"
    Installing laravel/laravel (v10.2.6)
      - Installing laravel/laravel (v10.2.6): Extracting archive
    Created project in D:\Laravel/demo-app2
> @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Updating dependencies
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework[v10.10.0, ..., v10.28.0] require league/flysystem ^3.8.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[3.8.0, ..., 3.17.0].
    - league/flysystem[3.3.0, ..., 3.14.0] require league/mime-type-detection ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.14.0].
    - league/flysystem[3.15.0, ..., 3.17.0] require league/flysystem-local ^3.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem-local[3.15.0, 3.16.0].
    - league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.3.0] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.2.11) does not satisfy that requirement.    - league/mime-type-detection[1.4.0, ..., 1.14.0] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
    - league/flysystem-local[3.15.0, ..., 3.16.0] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's 
fileinfo extension.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^10.10 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v10.10.0, ..., v10.28.0].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\Program Files\php-8.2.11\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
```

I don't understand the errors or what I need to do to fix most of them. I'm guessing that installing league/flysystem, league/mime-type-detection, and flysystem-local will get rid of the 1st three errors but I really don't know what will resolve the others.

Can anyone advise me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [requires ext-fileinfo. How do I add that into my composer.json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771117/requires-ext-fileinfo-how-do-i-add-that-into-my-composer-json-file)

Comment: Fix the obvious errors, and it may fix the less obvious issues. It's trying to downgrade because it can't satisfy the requirements.

Comment: @aynber - Sorry, but the first suggestion doesn't help. I edit php.ini as requested but now I get a new error saying InProjectInstaller.php line 69: mkdir(): permission denied. Trying your second suggestion next.

Comment: `mkdir` means that the installer doesn't have permissions to write to certain directories, so you'll need to check your file and directory permissions, and make sure that the user you're logged in as has permission to write to those.

Answer (score 0):

Check your **php.ini** file and uncomment `extension=fileinfo`
To uncomment just remove the `;` before line