PHPSpreadsheet x Docker: installation failed
I'm trying to install PHPSpreadsheet via composer using docker. I made this dockerfile, but I get the following error despite several attempts to fix it. Any idea why?
Here's my dockerfile:
FROM php:7.2-apache
RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql

COPY --from=composer/composer:latest-bin /composer /usr/bin/composer

# Create a working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN composer require "ext-gd:*" --ignore-platform-reqs
RUN composer require "ext-fileinfo:*" --ignore-platform-reqs
RUN composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet:1.18.0 --ignore-platform-reqs

RUN service apache2 restart

The error:
>>> RUN composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet:1.18.0 --ignore-platform-reqs
  23 |
  24 |     # Files datas
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet:1.18.0 --ignore-platform-reqs" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1


Version 1.17.0 and 1.18.0 aren't the same. To help you we also need the error from the composer. I think the other 2 packages use the newest PHP version and are therefor incompatible with phpoffice/phpspreadsheet:1.18.0 which uses "php": "^7.2 || ^8.0". To solve this issue you need also to specify the correct versions of the other 2 packages.

What you are doing here smells badly. You generally do not want to write require commands in the image generation, but to copy a composer.json and composer.lock and run  composer install while building the image.

Why are you using --ignore-platform-reqs? You haven't installed the requirements that phpspreadsheet needs and now composer is failing because you have those pieces missing. phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.18.0 requires ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.

According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771117/requires-ext-fileinfo-how-do-i-add-that-into-my-composer-json-file the fileinfo is built in by default. So you don't need it to install with composer, just make sure, the related extension is enabled in the apache config. I suppose with gd it's the same. And yes, write your own composer.json, copy it into the container and run run composer update.

@1stthomas they are not actually installing the extension. They are simply declaring that it is required. Running composer require ext-whatever does not install anything. Composer does not install extensions. And no, they shouldn't run composer update, they should run composer install, (after generating the lockfile).

Is that really the full and exact error message?

Also, keep in mind that v1.18.0 is more than three years old and has known security issues. PHP 7.2 is out of support since three years and should no longer be used in any production system

When I build your image without the extension lines (and w/o --ignore-platform-reqs) I get following error: phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.18.0 requires ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension. Therefor you need to expand your Dockerfile with enabling the 2 extensions. Have a look at: https://hub.docker.com/_/php.
